# Reading columns with different valuetypes

Tags: cassandra, hector

A SliceQuery< Long, String, String > says the keytype is long, column name is string and column value is string. When I execute the slice query using QueryResult < ColumnSlice< String, String > > I can get all the columns, but the key is long so there must be a column whose value is long type. It's a bit confusing for me to see how type safety works here(since query result will get a column type ). 
Also, if there is a column with value type other than string, then problem must arise.

How to have a generic slicequery that can be used to query columns of different value types ?

P.S : I am new to cassandra/hector.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  The first type is the type of the row key as you point out, but the row key is not stored as a column.  The row key is stored off in some other special place.  This is one of those gotcha's that folks coming from the relational DB world (like me) trip over.

As for how to manage column values with different types, there's a two-pronged approach.  First, you store the value as a byte array and serialize it yourself. Second, you key off of the column name to tell you which column - and therefore which value type - you're dealing with.  Once you know the correct type you can use the appropriate Serializer to deserialize the byte value into a variable of the correct type.  For your own complex objects and special types, you can write your own serializers.