# Cassandra createSliceQuery clarification

Tags: cassandra, thrift, hector

I'm trying to retrieve all columns of a row in Cassandra using Thrift 1.0 lib. I found some examples by Googling , in particular:

```
SliceQuery<String, String, String> sliceQuery = hectorTemplate.createSliceQuery(
    StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("myname");
sliceQuery.setKey("myid");
sliceQuery.setRange(null, null, false, 20);
QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String,String>> queryResult = sliceQuery.execute();
ColumnSlice<String,String> slice = queryResult.get();
List<HColumn<String, String>> retrievedColumns = slice.getColumns();
for (HColumn<String, String> column : retrievedColumns) {
    System.out.println(column.getName() +"::"+ column.getValue());
}
```

However, I could not find any information on what those parameters and types in Hector objects are??

For example, here:

```
SliceQuery<String, String, String>
```

- all types here are String - what are they types of? Column name type? column value types?

Then, we specify parameters to the createSliceQuery():

```
hectorTemplate.createSliceQuery(
    StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
```

Again - what are those serializers for? why are there only 3 serializers - is if for the first and last column, and something else? What if I get many columns, how do I specify serializers for them?

Then, we retrieve

```
List<HColumn<String, String>>
```

-- again, what are these String types for?
If I have a column of type BytesType - where do I specify that?

If there are some decent API docs (not just method signatures with no explanation of what their parameters are) - could you point me to them?

thanks!
Marina

Comment: ohhhhh.. hold on. hold on please. can you ask one question at a time? Rather select an API, may be astyanax, hector, native binary driver or pelops and can ask question based on them?

Comment: This is a good question about the Hector API (I don't understand why it is not clear to you which API is in question). Indeed, the Hector javadoc does not seem to document the generic types.

Comment: For what it's worth, have a look at Pelops. It's an excellently designed and documented Cassandra client library. I never understood why most people go for Hector.

Comment: Abhi, Tom - yes, my questions are about the Hector API. Why most people use it - not sure, maybe because when you Google for examples of Cassandra JAva-based clients, it is the one that shows up most, even though their API docs are a joke - all they show is method signatures, with zero info about what those parameters actually mean...

Comment: @abhi this is really just one question, I probably expressed it in too many words :) - whether somebody could either provide or point to information about the meaning of parameters and their types in Hector APIs.

Comment: ok Marina. Here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `SliceQuery<K, C, V>`, here are the type parameters:

> K -- The type of the key
>
> C -- The type of the column name
>
> V -- The type of the column value

Again in case of `HColumn<N,V>`, type parameters are

> N -- The type of the column name
>
> V -- The type of the column value

Similar the case of `createSliceQuery`

Comment: Thank, abhi, this makes sense. One more clarification: in case of SLiceQuery, we are getting back a list of columns, and their types most likely will be different. However, we are specifying this list as: List<HColumn<String, String>>, which to me looks like we are expecting all columns to be of type <String, String> ... How will the different types work in this case? Thanks!!

Comment: go through this blog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086186/reading-columns-with-different-valuetypes. Still if it not clear to you, then let me know